# Confusion about Php Long Polling with MSSQL

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, database, long-polling

In a nutshell, with long polling, you use a php server file that keeps looping in a while loop until new data in the database changed. Then it exits the while loop and returns the data. I am using SQL-SERVER, wouldn't querying the database that many times, across hundreds of thousands of users completely crash the database? The new site I am building has potential, and I want to make sure it can be expanded in case of rapid growth. As an example, it is going to have real time chat like facebook does, and it will have new content being posted (such as other users posts). Thanks!

Comment: longpolling is obsolete anyways. there's far better methods to use than continually hammering on the db like a bored child in the back seat. "are we there yet? are we there yet? are we there yet?"

Comment: @MarcB What kinds of methods? Node.js?

Comment: node.js is a programming language/library. that's like saying "I should use a motor" when announcing your plan to go on a drive-around vacation. websockets are the go-to solution these days

Comment: Marc B how would web sockets replace long polling towards the sql server?